# How to unzip a multi-part zip archive with +4Gb files on Linux

Tags: linux, debian

I have received a multi-part zip archive from a colleague (who uses Windows as his desktop system), and I would like to extract the files (virtual machine images).

First try (plain `unzip`):

```
% unzip 'SATT ORG.zip' 'SATT ORG/Windows_Server_2003_Standard_Edition-disk1.vdi'
Archive:  SATT ORG.zip
warning [SATT ORG.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  115300
%
```

Reading a bit on the subject indicates that I should try with `zip -FF`.  After some experimentation I arrive at:

```
% % zip -FF 'SATT ORG.zip' --out fixed.zip
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
 Found end record (EOCDR) - says expect 9 splits
Scanning for entries...
  Found spanning marker - expected as this is split (multi-disk) archive...
 copying: SATT ORG/  (0 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/  (0 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/VBox.log  (19450 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/VBox.log.1  (19762 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/VBox.log.2  (19619 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/VBox.log.3  (19900 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Logs/VBoxStartup.log  (30701 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/SATT ORG.vbox  (2675 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/SATT ORG.vbox-prev  (2675 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Snapshots/  (0 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Windows_Server_2003_Standard_Edition-disk1.vdi  (4959998416 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Windows_Server_2003_Standard_Edition-disk2.vdi  (6201052986 bytes)
 copying: SATT ORG/Windows_Server_2003_Standard_Edition-disk3.vdi  (6665110640 bytes)
Central Directory found...
        zip warning: Entry too big:SATT ORG/Windows_Server_2003_Standard_Edition-disk1.vdi

zip error: Entry too big to split, read, or write (Poor compression resulted in unexpectedly large entry - try -fz)
%
```

I've also experimented with `jar` and a Python script, but without any luck.

Suggestions are most welcome.  (I have a Windows system somewhere in the basement and a sufficiently large, exfat formatted USB memory stick, so even a solution which requires a trip past Windows may be workable.)

Comment: Ask your colleague to use 7-zip instead.

Comment: I've been informed that it probably has been generated with WinRAR, so I'll give that a try once I get to a Windows system.

Comment: WinRAR really needs to be wiped off the face of the earth...